# shadowing and shadowed symbol get mixed in symtable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following function definition, where the exception name `e` shadows a parameter:

```
def f(a,e):
  try:
    raise RuntimeError('test')
  except RuntimeError as e:
    pass
```

In the symbol table of function `f` I would expect three symbols: two parameters `a,e` (not assigned) and one local `e`, which has been assigned. But the symbol table contains two symbols: parameter `a`, which has not been assigned, and parameter `e`, which has been assigned. It seems that the properties of the unassigned parameter `e` and the exception name `e` are combined into one symbol. Does that make sense?

See the following test code:

```
import symtable

def symStat(sym):
  stat = []
  if sym.is_parameter(): stat.append('param')
  if sym.is_assigned(): stat.append('assigned')
  if sym.is_referenced(): stat.append('referenced')
  return stat

INDENT_STR = '  '
def printSymsRec(st, indentLevel=0):
  indent = indentLevel*INDENT_STR
  print('%s%s:' % (indent, st.get_name()),
        [(sym.get_name(), symStat(sym)) for sym in st.get_symbols()])
  for stc in st.get_children():
    printSymsRec(stc, indentLevel+1)

TEST_CODE = """
def f(a,e):
  try:
    raise RuntimeError('test')
  except RuntimeError as e:
    pass
""".strip()

symRoot = symtable.symtable(TEST_CODE, "<string>", "exec")
printSymsRec(symRoot)
```

which gives the following output:

```
top: [('f', ['assigned'])]
  f: [('a', ['param']), ('e', ['param', 'assigned']), ('RuntimeError', ['referenced'])]
```

Why is the output not like the following:

```
...
  f: [('a', ['param']), ('e', ['param']), ('e', ['assigned']), ...]
```

Comment: @Stephen Not a duplicate. In that case OP thinks the `while` loop creates a scope.

Comment: There is only one `e` symbol there. Parameters are local variables; there's no separate namespace for parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters aren't special in this regard, they're just like any other name. So when `except RuntimeError as e` assigns to `e`, it overwrites the parameter's value. And this isn't specific to `except` statements; you can get the same behaviour from a simple assignment:

```
TEST_CODE = "def f(e): e = 0"
symRoot = symtable.symtable(TEST_CODE, "<string>", "exec")
printSymsRec(symRoot.get_children()[0])
# -> f: [('e', ['param', 'assigned'])]
```

Comment: Ok, I get it: `except ... as e` is - when looking at the name `e` - equivalent to `e = ...`. So the exception name `e` does not shadow the parameter, it remains a parameter. And additionally it gets a value assigned.

Comment: @coproc Yeah, exactly. I just added an example about that too.